# Removing Dollar and comma from string

Tags: java, regex, str-replace

How can we remove dollar sign ($) and all comma(,) from same string? Would it be better to avoid regex?

```
String liveprice = "$123,456.78";
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

do like this

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
Number number = format.parse("\$123,456.78");
System.out.println(number.toString());
```

**output**

```
123456.78
```

Comment: I really want this. You make my day. Thanks :)

Comment: My value is 1,000 then is gives java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "1,000" (at offset 5)

Comment: Is '$' the currency character for your local?

Comment: wtf: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "$39.39"`

Comment: Without specifying a locale, I got this error: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "$1,234.56"` --but this made it work: `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse(sourceStr)`

Answer (score 26):

Try,

```
String liveprice = "$123,456.78";
String newStr = liveprice.replaceAll("[$,]", "");
```

`replaceAll` uses regex, to avoid regex than try with consecutive `replace` method.

```
 String liveprice = "$1,23,456.78";
 String newStr = liveprice.replace("$", "").replace(",", "");
```

Comment: he wants to avoid regex

Comment: OP said "Would be better if we avoid regex."

Answer (score 3):

Without regex, you can try this:

```
String output = "$123,456.78".replace("$", "").replace(",", "");
```

Comment: This will put gap `' '` between number.

Answer (score 2):

Here is more information [Oracle JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
liveprice = liveprice.replace("X", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this works?

```
String liveprice = "$123,456.78";
String newStr = liveprice.replace("$", "").replace(",","");
```

Output: `123456.78`

### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/TiL4Ao)

Better One:

```
String liveprice = "$123,456.78";
String newStr = liveprice.replaceAll("[$,]", "")
```

### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/BgGS4C)

Comment: @Jesper Is that fine now?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Replace` instead

```
String liveprice = "$123,456.78";
String output = liveprice.replace("$", "");
output = output .replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, @Prabhakaran's answer did not work, someone can try this.

```
String salary = employee.getEmpSalary().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
Float empSalary = Float.parseFloat(salary);
```

Comment: While this does work, some might criticize regEx as being slow and tricky. Of course, as we see, figuring out lib calls and options is tricky also. An all-purpose powerful lib, is in many cases an intricate puzzle that seems unable to cover the problem at-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Is a replace really what you need?

```
public void test() {
  String s = "$123,456.78";
  StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
  for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if ( Character.isDigit(ch)) {
      t.append(ch);
    }
  }
}
```

This will work for any decorated number.

Answer (score 0):

Example using Swedish Krona currency

String x="19.823.567,10 kr";

```
        x=x.replace(".","");
        x=x.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        x=x.replace(",", ".");
        x=x.replaceAll("[^0-9 , .]", "");
```

System.out.println(x);

Will give the output ->19823567.10(which can now be used  for any computation)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.NumberFormat

def currencyAmount = 9876543.21 //Default is BigDecimal
def currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance( Locale.US )

assert currencyFormatter.format( currencyAmount ) == "9,876,543.21"
```

Don't need `getCurrencyInstance()` if currency is not required.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you could use regex. For example:

```
"19.823.567,10 kr".replace(/\D/g, '')
```