# Java Tax Calculator Jtextfield must replace if user inputs $ commas % spaces

Tags: java

I need to replace spaces commas $ % typed in the jtextfield on my taxcalculator code. But at the same time I need to fix it because when I try to run it again it does not because the validation adds $ to the field. This a simple form of validation such that if the user enters “$1, 499. 97” it will be converted to “1499.97”.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TaxCalculator7F extends JApplet {
    JLabel subTotalJLabel, taxRateJLabel, totalTaxJLabel, totalSaleJLabel;
    JTextField subTotalJTextField, taxRateJTextField, totalTaxJTextField, totalSaleJTextField;
    JButton calculateTaxJButton;

    public void init() {
        setLayout(null);  // allows explicit positioning of GUI components

        Container myContent = getContentPane();

        subTotalJLabel = new JLabel();
        subTotalJLabel.setText("Sub Total: ");
        subTotalJLabel.setBounds(10, 0, 100, 25);
        myContent.add(subTotalJLabel);

        subTotalJTextField = new JTextField();
        subTotalJTextField.setText("0.00");
        subTotalJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        subTotalJTextField.setBounds(90, 0, 80, 25);
        myContent.add(subTotalJTextField);

        taxRateJLabel = new JLabel();
        taxRateJLabel.setText("Tax Rate (%): ");
        taxRateJLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
        myContent.add(taxRateJLabel);

        taxRateJTextField = new JTextField();
        taxRateJTextField.setText("7");
        taxRateJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        taxRateJTextField.setBounds(90, 40, 80, 25);
        myContent.add(taxRateJTextField);

        totalTaxJLabel = new JLabel();
        totalTaxJLabel.setText("Tax Due: ");
        totalTaxJLabel.setBounds(10, 80, 100, 25);
        myContent.add(totalTaxJLabel);

        totalTaxJTextField = new JTextField();
        totalTaxJTextField.setEditable(false);
        totalTaxJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        totalTaxJTextField.setBounds(90, 80, 80, 25);
        myContent.add(totalTaxJTextField);

        totalSaleJLabel = new JLabel();
        totalSaleJLabel.setText("Total Sale: ");
        totalSaleJLabel.setBounds(10, 120, 100, 25);
        myContent.add(totalSaleJLabel);

        totalSaleJTextField = new JTextField();
        totalSaleJTextField.setEditable(false);
        totalSaleJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        totalSaleJTextField.setBounds(90, 120, 80, 25);
        myContent.add(totalSaleJTextField);

        calculateTaxJButton = new JButton();
        calculateTaxJButton.setText("Calculate Tax");
        calculateTaxJButton.setBounds(20, 160, 140, 30);
        myContent.add(calculateTaxJButton);


        calculateTaxJButton.addActionListener(
                    event -> {
                        // define variables
                        double subTotal, taxRate, taxDue, totalSale;

                        // get sales sub total and tax rate
                        subTotal = Double.parseDouble(subTotalJTextField.getText());
                        //subTotalJTextField.getText();
                        //Code to clear from field $ % ,
                        //subTotalJTextField.setText(String.valueOf(subTotal).replaceAll("(?<=\\d),(?=\\d)|\\$", ""));
                        taxRate = Double.parseDouble(taxRateJTextField.getText());

                        taxDue = subTotal * taxRate / 100;
                        totalSale = subTotal + taxDue;

                        DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
                        DecimalFormat percent = new DecimalFormat("0.0%");

                        // test strings
                        subTotalJTextField.setText(dollars.format(subTotal));

                        taxRateJTextField.setText(percent.format(taxRate / 100.00));

                        totalTaxJTextField.setText(dollars.format(taxDue));
                        totalSaleJTextField.setText(dollars.format(totalSale));
                    }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: How does it crash? please show your stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$100.00"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at TaxCalculator7F.lambda$init$0(TaxCalculator7F.java:72)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you could `replace` the `$` sign

```
subTotal = Double.parseDouble(subTotalJTextField.getText().replace ("$", ""));
```

and the tax rate would be

```
taxRate = Double.parseDouble(taxRateJTextField.getText().replace ("%", ""));
```

or as @nandha points out

```
    String money = "$1,234,000.67";
    try {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        Number number = format.parse(money);
        System.out.println(number.doubleValue());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, still does not let me run it again. Only runs on the first try.

Comment: I guess you are going to need to do it for `taxRate = Double.parseDouble(taxRateJTextField.getText());` as well.  Is there some new error coming up?

Comment: Ok, I did something now to check, the problem is the % on the tax Rate. Thanks, how can I add to that code on .replace ("$ ", "") to replace commas and spaces as well?

Comment: I got it working at the second try with this thanks. But I need to add to it to also replace commas and spaces to " "

Comment: Ok. I have tried the answer you gave me . I added it to the code but to the replace. How would it be to include replace , $ spaces %

Comment: You can chain them so `taxRateJTextField.getText().replace ("$", "").replace (",", "").replace (" ", "").replace ("%", "")`

Comment: Perfect! Now it works ! Sorry if I am a noob, I am beggining to code comming from visual studio and I still need to learn more. Thank you.

Comment: No problem - have fun

Answer (score 1):

```
    String subValue = subTotalJTextField.getText();
    try {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        Number number = format.parse(subValue);
        subTotal = number.doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        subTotal = 0;
    }
```

Try this.
Refer  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351323/removing-dollar-and-comma-from-string) for more info

Comment: plus1 and linked to your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think below code suits well to your problem

```
Number amount = null, rate = null;
try {
    amount = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse(subTotalJTextField.getText());
    rate = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parse(taxRateJTextField.getText());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    amount = 0.0;
    rate = 0.0;
}
subTotal = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(amount));
taxRate = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(rate));
```